# Sitecore: Error upon adding a rendering to a Placeholder

Tags: sitecore

[View Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWcmN.jpg)
I am working on the exercise project and cannot seem to add a rendering to a placeholder using the Experience Editor. The site gives a javascript error(albeit, a very vague one) with the following error in the logs:

Nested Exception

```
Exception: Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ExceptionWrapper
Message: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IContro
ller.
Source: System.Web.Mvc
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestConte
xt requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext re
questContext, String controllerName)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(Reques
tContext requestContext, String controllerName)
```

I have searched everywhere with no solution. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

**EDIT**

**Model**:

```
 public class FeaturedEvents
    {

        public FeaturedEvents()
        {

        }
        public HtmlString Heading { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Intro { get; set; }

        public HtmlString EventImage  { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
   public class FeaturedEventController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(CreateModel());
        }

        private static FeaturedEvents CreateModel()
        {
            var item = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;
            var FeaturedEvent = new FeaturedEvents()
            {
                Heading = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "ContentHeading")),
                EventImage = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Event Image", "mw=400")),
                Intro = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, "ContentIntro"))
            };

            return FeaturedEvent;


        }
    }
```

**Route**

I am using the default route. I wasn't instructed to change it.

I have created a controller rendering and linked the placeholders as well. But, as soon as I select the rendering for the placeholder in the Experience Editor, it gives me the "An Error occurred" pop up dialog.

**Trace**
Server Error in '/' Application.

The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Source Error:

```
Line 84:         <div class="container">
Line 85:             <div class="row">
Line 86:                 @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("FeaturedEvent")
Line 87: 
Line 88:
```

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ssd.tac.local\Website\Views\TAC\Events\HomeContent.cshtml    Line: 86

Stack Trace:

```html
    [ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.]
    
    [ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'FeaturedEvent'. 
    The context item is: '/sitecore/content/Events/Home'. 
    The current route url is: '{*pathInfo}'. This is the default Sitecore route which is set up in the 'InitializeRoutes' processor of the 'initialize' pipeline. ]
       Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +172
       Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.GetController() +23
       Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute() +43
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +134
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +184
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
       Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
       ASP._Page_Views_TAC_Events_HomeContent_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ssd.tac.local\Website\Views\TAC\Events\HomeContent.cshtml:86
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
    
    [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/TAC/Events/HomeContent.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
    ]
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +184
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
       Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
       ASP._Page_Views_TAC_Events_One_Column_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ssd.tac.local\Website\Views\TAC\Events\One-Column.cshtml:8
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
    
    [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/TAC/Events/One-Column.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
    ]
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +184
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
       Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
       ASP._Page_Views_TAC_Events_Events_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ssd.tac.local\Website\Views\TAC\Events\Events.cshtml:93
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
    
    [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/TAC/Events/Events.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
    ]
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +302
       System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +375
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +90
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +37
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet for the controller and also the route you are using?

Comment: Updated the question good Sir :)

Comment: events.tac.local.Controllers.FeaturedEventController, events.tac.local. 
I am using fully qualified name here now. I tried the normal way before which is, just use the controller name (minus the "Controller") and Index in the view.

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the issue on a local instance. I have created the controller rendering in Sitecore as shown below

[image]

and update the code accordingly. I have then try to add the rendering on the Experience Editor. This eventually caused the same error.

**Solution**

The issue was because the `dll` referencing the Controller was not in the bin folder. So, please make sure that the assembly referencing the Controller is in the bin folder.

Also, even if the dll is in the bin folder, it may be that it is not being overwritten with the new one. You may try to copy and paste the dll into the bin folder.

Comment: Nothing changed. Still the same exception and error.

Comment: Can you please share the View you are using along with the name

Comment: **Index**

 (@)model events.tac.local.Models.FeaturedEvents

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="Event-Detail.html">
            (@)Model.EventImage
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>  (@)Model.Heading</h3>
            <p>
                 (@)Model.Intro
            </p>
            <a href="Event-Detail.html" class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
-------------------

(@) is without ().

Comment: Yes. The name of the view is Index.

Comment: The routing seems to work because I am able to land on the pages with controlling rendering. Also, I am not sure how to map the routing :(

Comment: Thanks. I hope we fix it.

Comment: I have updated the answer completely and remove some unnecessary comment. Please see the updated answer

Comment: I am using the following in my controller:
using events.tac.local.Models;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

So I need to cross check if I have all the dlls in the bin? Also kindly can you tell me which bin exactly? The Root or my VS project?

Comment: You should add your project dll. Example events.tac.dll

Comment: I copied the references and now both my Visual studio project and the webroot bin has those references. Still no luck :(. Same issue same trace.

Comment: Did you copy your project dll to the bin? I mean the Project Assembly. It should be present in the bin folder in the website folder